# How to serialize/deserialize only base class properties with DataContractSerializer?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, datacontractserializer

What would be the simplest way of serializing and deserializing the declared types of properties only, ignoring the fact that the actual object is more derived than declared? For instance, with these classes:

```
[DataContract]
public class Base
{
    [DataMember]
    string BaseProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    string DerivedProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to be able to achieve the equivalent of this:

```
Base baseObject = new Derived();
var baseSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Base));

using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite("file"))
using (var writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter(fileStream))
{
    baseSerializer.WriteObject(writer, baseObject);
}

using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead("file"))
using (var reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateBinaryReader(fileStream, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()))
{
    var deserialized = (Base)baseSerializer.ReadObject(reader);
}
```

Provided example code fails because `Derived` is not a known type, of course. But I'm not interested in writing that additional information into a file, only what the base class provides.

Comment: Don't you need to add `KnownTypeAttribute` somewhere? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I know this can be made to work by simply adding `Derived` to the list of known types. But I explicitly do not want to do this. I wish to ignore the fact that the actual object is not a simple `Base`.

Comment: XmlDictionaryWriter tends to save type information. Just use serializers without default type support, for example JSON. In Newtonsoft.JSON you can specify serialization contract in which you specify what to serialize and what should not be in general.

Comment: Is it important that you use the DataContractSerializer? Otherwise you could try with the XmlSerializer, which works without all that extra notation.

Comment: @Michael XmlSerializer also needs a list of known types, if I recall correctly. It would fail here as well. And it doesn't have other features I'd like, like deserializing read-only properties.

Comment: @eocron DataContractJsonSerializer fails with the same issue. It doesn't know the derived type.

Comment: Do you ever need to deserialize the properties of `Derived`?

Comment: The user said they only wanted the base class properties serialized/deserialized.  I think my answer below more than meets the needs and deserves an up vote.  There is error checking that could be done, there are ways to make sure you grab the lowest base class, but that I leave up to the user if the need arises.  As far as I am concern, my answer works for the question asked.

Comment: @user1628733 - Yes, your answer makes sense.  Along the same lines one could use something like [tag:automapper] to map the derived class to the base.  But if they *never* need to serialize derived properties then some shortcuts are possible.

Comment: Yes Automapper is a very nice library and would also work perfectly in this scenario

Answer (score 3):

This solution uses reflection to grab the properties of the base class and sets a new instance of your base class values on the derived class values.  It solves your current problem but may not solve all problems.

Best of luck, that is the fun of programming and I'm sure you will have to modify this some!

```
    [DataContract]
    public class Base
    {
        [DataMember]
        string BaseProperty { get; set; }

        public void SetBase(string val)
        {
            BaseProperty = val;
        }
    }

    public class Derived : Base
    {
        public Derived()
        {
            SetBase("TestWorks");
        }

        string DerivedProperty { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj = new Derived();

        Base baseObject = GetBaseObject<Base, Derived>(obj);

        var baseSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Base));

        using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite("file"))
        using (var writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter(fileStream))
        {
            baseSerializer.WriteObject(writer, baseObject);
        }

        using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead("file"))
        using (var reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateBinaryReader(fileStream, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()))
        {
            var deserialized = (Base)baseSerializer.ReadObject(reader);
        }
    }

    public static TBase GetBaseObject<TBase, T>(T obj) where TBase : new() where T : TBase
    {
        TBase bObj = new TBase();

        var bProps = bObj.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

        foreach (var bProp in bProps)
        {
            bProp.SetValue(bObj,
                obj.GetType().BaseType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                .First(p => p.Name == bProp.Name).GetValue(obj));
        }

        return bObj;
    }
```