# `DataContractSerializer` deserialize child class into base class

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontractserializer

I have following on my server:

```
[DataContract]
public class Base { }

[OperationContract]
void DoSth(Base base) { }
```

and on my client:

```
class Child : Base { }
```

When calling the server with `DoSth(child)` I get a serialization exception, because `Child` is not known to the WCF DataContractSerializer:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:base. The InnerException message was 'Type 'Child' with data contract name 'Child:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Client' is not expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.
 ---> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 'Child' with data contract name 'Child:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Client' is not expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.
```

And I don't want to make it known, because the server uses only `Base`'s properties. How can I send my data as `Base object`

I know, I could create a new `Base` object and copy all properties, but this is not really elegant.

---

Following @QiYou's answer:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Base", Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Server")]
class Child : Base { }
```

also doesn't work, because the underlying types of the data contract differ.

Comment: Is the exception thrown on the client side or the server side?  Might you please [edit] your question to share the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s), if any?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to serialize/deserialize only base class properties with DataContractSerializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41895084/how-to-serialize-deserialize-only-base-class-properties-with-datacontractseriali)

Comment: @defaultUsernameN: I already saw that question. I can also manually create a new object, but in my opinion, that should not be required. My child object should just be serialized as base class.

Comment: Try this answer [Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316118/constructor-in-wcf-datacontract-not-reflected-on-client)

Comment: @QIYou, nope, this also doesn't help.

Comment: @dbc I added the exception to the question.

Comment: You *can't* use arbitrary classes with SOAP or for that matter, any communication protocol. The server on the other side wouldn't know what to do with the unknown `Child` class. At best it would *ignore* all additional properties. Is this a SOAP service? In that case there's a WSDL file that can be used to generate the classes and the client. Visual Studio can generate client classes with `Add Service Reference`. In the command line you can use `svcutil`

Comment: `should not be required.` it *is* required. This isn't a matter of opinion, it's the law - it's part of the SOAP protocol itself. The WSDL and XSD schemas specify what client and server can exchange among themselves. Anything else is invalid. That's what allows clients and servers written in any language to talk to each other. The DataContract attributes are an easy way to specify the operations and DTOs in code instead of schema documents.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I actually want a `Base` class to be sent and all `Child`'s properties to be ignored.

Comment: @AchimStuy - Happy to be proven wrong, but I do not believe that `DataContractSerializer` has an extension point that allows for contract customization in the same way as XmlSerializer's `XmlAttributeOverrides` or Json.NET's `DefaultContractResolver`.  Your best option would seem to be to construct a surrogate -- which could be an instance of `Base` itself.  See [Data Contract Surrogates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/data-contract-surrogates).  Implementing making `Child` implement `IXmlSerializer` and doing everything manually would be another option.

Comment: Thanks, @dbc. Are surrogates also supported in .NET (Core)?

Comment: @AchimStuy - yes, but the API is different in .NET Core and .NET Framework.  In core you need to use [`DataContractSerializerExtensions.SetSerializationSurrogateProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializerextensions.setserializationsurrogateprovider).  Also I don't believe surrogates ever got implemented for `DataContractJsonSerializer` in .NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it with WCF's template example.

I inherit in the client's **Reference.cs**:

Here's an example:

Server-side:

```
    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
   
        bool boolValue = true;
        string stringValue = "Hello ";

        [DataMember]    
            public bool BoolValue
            {
                get { return boolValue; }
                set { boolValue = value; }
            }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
{
    get { return stringValue; }
    set { stringValue = value; }
}
        }
```

client-side:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name = "CompositeType", Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService4")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    public class Child : CompositeType
    {
        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue { get; set; }
    
    }
```

At the moment the test program can run, you can try my method.

Comment: Your approach makes sense. But on my end it still fails, because the underlying types of the data contracts are not equal. From the client I want to send `Child`s and `CompositeType`s.

Comment: No, I don't mean to add a attribute directly on top of the inheritance class: **[DataContract(Name = "Base", Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Server")]**. I've actually added a lot of attributes: **[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name = "CompositeType", Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService4")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]**